# Cómo filtrar las conexiones de las bases de datos en PgAdmin a Heroku?

Tags: base-de-datos, postgresql, heroku, pgadmin

Quiero utilizar una base remota por medio de Heroku, pero resulta que cuando me conecto a dicha base de datos de Heroku por medio de PgAdmin, resulta bastante engorroso tener que buscar el nombre exacto, como sucede de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y quisiera que sólo apareciera la base de datos con la cual estoy interactuando:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Esta es la base de datos con la cual estoy conectado, pero buscarlo manualmente es muy demorado

Adicionalmente vi en foros que una forma para realizar ese filtro (que sólo aparezca la base de datos deseada, era a partir de esta configuración al momento de registrar el servidor:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero no me ha generado los resultados esperados.
Cuál sería la forma exitosa de poder lograr dicho filtro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno yo estoy teniendo exactamente el mismo problema, la única solución que encontré es usar otra GUI, en mi caso usé el [DBeaver](https://dbeaver.io). De esta manera ya solo me muestra la base de datos la cual tengo acceso, hasta ahora funciona bien.
Bueno para ser un poco mas específico si interesa. Al momento de añadir la nueva conexión fui en la parte donde dice “Connection details (name…)” y luego en la parte que dice "DataBases / Catalogs" y en “include” y pues añades el nombre de la base de datos que tienes acceso.  (NOTA: la versión del DBeaver es la 22.1.3.202207240747).
Saludos.